# It is necessary to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() each time?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())` in my `GlobalActivity`.

```
public class GlobalActivity extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}
```

Do I need to call it again each time I am using facebook sdk?
I have a `Fragment` with a `LoginButton`.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is Initialize once in Application class thats enough. when new  activity created FacebookSdk automatically Initialized.

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
public class ApplicationName extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
// Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
}
```